# How useful is experience/knowledge in data engineering for scientific jobs?

Tags: job-search, career-development, careers

I was wondering (as shown by the title) how useful experience in data engineering could be for future scientific work.  In other words, could it be useful if you wanted to do physics and engineering work?  It seems like it might be since laboratories working with material engineering, particle physics, and nuclear physics need to process a lot of data and this could be an alternative means of working for companies or laboratories.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd say that totally depends on what exactly you want to do. "Scientific jobs" is a very vague term. You could totally be a data engineer (or something similar) for a scientific company. But if you want to become a researcher for example, it probably won't be enough (it would probably help a bit though).